# Adding a symbol to nodes near coords in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, symbols, nodes-near-coords

I'm currently making a bar plot with pgfplots and have numbers in percent on the x axis. I want to show the values directly at the bars for which I use `nodes near coords`. But because the values are given as numerical, I need to add the `%` by hand. I could this for the axis labels via `xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\textsf{\%}}`, but this didn't work for the `nodes near coords`.

I tried the `point meta` command, but it didn't work as expected. I read through the manual chapter 4.8, but couldn't find any help regarding adding a simple symbol to the nodes label.

Here's my MWE, which yields the (almost) wanted result, without the percent-symbols at the bars values:

```
 \documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}

 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        height=5cm,
        width=12cm,
        axis y line*=left,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        enlarge y limits=0.3,
%%%     
        xmin=0, xmax=20,
        xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\textsf{\%}},
%%%
        symbolic y coords={one, two, three},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords,
%       point meta={x},
     ]

        \addplot[
            draw=black!30,
            fill=black!30
        ] 
        coordinates {(10,one) (18,two) (5,three)};

        \addplot[
            draw=black!70,
            fill=black!70
        ] 
        coordinates {(9,one) (8,two) (7,three)};
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Using something like `point meta={x\%}` only yields errors and I couldn't find any working solution.

Best regards